# PHP MySQL UPDATE only one Cell, instead of whole row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So i have a table with a row, click on 'bearbeiten', i get to a formula where i can fill in the changed name or whatever, and then everything changes instead of only the fields i wrote something in and the rest stays.

So if i would only change name and click on save, every other field in the table goes blank.

I tried it with WHERE already, and read that POST is a good method but i think i can change it with making a few changes in the $sql statement, just don't know what.

```
<?php
//if(isset($...)
if($_GET['aktion'] == "speichern")
{    
$ID             = $_GET['ID'];
$Anrede         = $_GET['Anrede'];
$Nachname       = $_GET['Nachname'];
$Vorname        = $_GET['Vorname'];
$Geburtsdatum   = $_GET['Geburtsdatum'];
$Telefonnummer  = $_GET['Telefonnummer'];
$Email          = $_GET['Email'];


$sql = "UPDATE Adressbuch SET Anrede = '$Anrede', Nachname = '$Nachname',Vorname = '$Vorname', Geburtsdatum = '$Geburtsdatum', Telefonnummer = '$Telefonnummer', Email = '$Email' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";

echo '<a href="adressbuch-abfragen">Zurueck zum Adressbuch</a><br>';
require_once ('konfiguration.php');

$db_erg = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql)
    or die("Anfrage fehlgeschlagen: " . mysqli_error($db_con));

        exit;
}
```

Comment: i love those german posts

Comment: ignore the echo and my variable names x)

Comment: Arent the Fields populated when you call the Page?

Comment: no, when i get to the formula everything is blank, its like making a new row .

Comment: So if you want to change an Entry, it is likely that you already have Data in the Database. Why don't you output them and populate the Fields? And when you save them, everything stays the same, except the Changes you make.

Comment: @EstebanP. wos isn leicht? ;P

Comment: Oh thats a good idea, so i have to look into that first cause i wouldn't know how to start right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:
Just update the column, if you variable is not blank, else update it with the same value as the record already has.

```
UPDATE Adressbuch 
   SET Anrede =         CASE WHEN '$Anrede' != ''        THEN '$Anrede'        ELSE Anrede        END
      ,Nachname =       CASE WHEN '$Nachname' != ''      THEN '$Nachname'      ELSE Nachname      END
      ,Vorname =        CASE WHEN '$Vorname' != ''       THEN '$Vorname'       ELSE Vorname       END
      ,Geburtsdatum =   CASE WHEN '$Geburtsdatum' != ''  THEN '$Geburtsdatum'  ELSE Geburtsdatum  END
      ,Telefonnummer =  CASE WHEN '$Telefonnummer' != '' THEN '$Telefonnummer' ELSE Telefonnummer END
      ,Email =          CASE WHEN '$Email' != ''         THEN '$Email'         ELSE Email         END
 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: i tried it like that too, but didn't work somehow. This works perfectly, thanks ! I would still like to have the formula already filled in with the row that i chose and then just change the already set datas, but this works for the time i think about doing that^^

Answer (score 0):

Use as and see if it works. Thanks.

```
<?php 
require_once ('konfiguration.php');
//if(isset($...)
if($_GET['aktion'] == "speichern")
{    
  $ID             = $_GET['ID'];
  $Anrede         = $_GET['Anrede'];
  $Nachname       = $_GET['Nachname'];
  $Vorname        = $_GET['Vorname'];
  $Geburtsdatum   = $_GET['Geburtsdatum'];
  $Telefonnummer  = $_GET['Telefonnummer'];
  $Email          = $_GET['Email'];

  //use where in your query to update the particular row
  //in below query id = your column in database table
  $sql = "UPDATE Adressbuch SET Anrede = '$Anrede', Nachname = '$Nachname',Vorname = '$Vorname', Geburtsdatum = '$Geburtsdatum', Telefonnummer = '$Telefonnummer', Email = '$Email' WHERE id='$ID'";

  $db_erg = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql) or die("Anfrage fehlgeschlagen: " . mysqli_error($db_con));

  echo '<a href="adressbuch-abfragen">Zurueck zum Adressbuch</a><br>';

  exit;
}
?>
```

Use POST method instead of GET.